# Google App Engine - Node.js with all locales

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have developed a Node.js application on my system. The app is using French locale and is working properly on my system because I installed Node.js with `--with-intl=system-icu` option.

When I deploy it to google using `gcloud app deploy` it doesn't work properly. I searched online and found that the default installation of Node.js doesn't contain all the locales.

Is there any way I can install Node.js with all locales for the Google App Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install things that are not offered by default in Google App Engine if you use [Custom Runtimes in the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart).

Custom Runtimes let you define your own Dockerfile where you can add commands like:

```
RUN npm install full-icu
```

I found this example for [Dockerizing a Node.js web app](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/), which may help you.